# Bug on reseting the ui images positions

Tags: objective-c

So currently right now I am having a frustrating bug with my images.

Lets start with right off the bat, what is the bug?
So the bug is when I add this particular code into my project.

```
-(void)addfive{
score = score + 1;
scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SCORE: %i", score];
scoreLabel.text = scoreString;


}
```

I put it into one of my voids

```
-(void)PoopandScore{

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(Poop.frame, toilet.frame)){
    [self addfive];
    [enemyMovementTimer invalidate];
    [self bugpositionenemy];

}


}
```

so you must be thinking whats the problem? Well when my toilet catches the poop the images all return to there places where they were on the view controller, then go back to where they are supposed to go. If I were to make a professional game I don't want the movement to be glitchy every time you catch a poop. can anyone please help me? I am a bit stuck and find coding very tiring. Thanks!

my position enemy looks like this

```
-(void)positionEnemy {
// Random enemy position
enemyPosition = arc4random() % 249;
enemyPosition = enemyPosition + 20;
// Set enemy Image location
Poop.center = CGPointMake(enemyPosition, -40);

// Set enemy speed
randomSpeed = speedOfEnemy;
switch (randomSpeed) {
    case 0:
        speedOfEnemy = 0.005;
        break;
    case 1:
        speedOfEnemy = 0.005;
    case 2:
        speedOfEnemy = 0.005;
    default:
        break;
}
```

if you need me to add any more information don't be afraid to ask me!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Had to turn off auto layout!